# Unit Test react-router onEnter/onLeave

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I've some logic runs at onEnter/onLeave. I've used some `setInterval` at onEnter and clear them at onLeave using `clearInterval`.

How can I unit test above case?

```
<Route
        component={App}
        onEnter={onEnterApp}
        onLeave={onLeaveApp}
        path="/app">
```

Below is my test case but it fails ,

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../components/views/app.jsx';
import {shallow, mount, render} from 'enzyme';
import {expect, assert} from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {mountWithIntl} from '../test_utils/intl-enzyme-test-helper.js';





describe(‘App renders correctly', () => {

    it('When mounting set intervals', () => {
        const wrapper = mountWithIntl(<App/>);
        expect(window.x).to.exist;
        expect(window.y).to.exist;
    });

    it('When unmounting clear intervals', () => {

        const wrapper = mountWithIntl(<App/>);
        wrapper.unmount();
        expect(window.x).to.not.exist;
        expect(window.y).to.not.exist;
    });

});
```

Comment: have you tried `global` instead of `windows`

Comment: thank you. It was an improvement but did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onEnter` and `onLeave` props aren't tied to the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` methods of your `<App>` component, so just mounting and unmounting the `<App>` will not call those functions.

Assuming you trust that React Router works, you can just test that your `onEnterApp` and `onLeaveApp` functions work properly

```
describe('onEnterApp', () => {
  it('sets x and y', () => {
    onEnterApp();
    expect(global.x).to.exist;
    expect(globa.y).to.exist;
  });
});
```

If you want to verify that they are run when the URL matches the `/app` path, then you will need to involve a `<Router>`.

```
import createMemoryHistory from 'react-router';

describe('App', () => {
  it('runs onEnterApp when navigating to /app', (done) => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory(['/app']);
    const holder = document.createElement('div');
    render((
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route
          component={App}
          onEnter={onEnterApp}
          onLeave={onLeaveApp}
          path="/app">
      </Router>
    ), holder, () => {
      expect(global.x).to.exist;
      expect(globa.y).to.exist;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Testing `onLeaveApp` would require you to navigate to a new location with your `history` instance and then test that the desired global state exists.

```
history.push({ pathname: '/foo' })
```

Comment: render , is this from enzyme ?

Comment: No, just the `react-dom` render. I'm not familiar enough with enzyme to write the answer using it, but the principal should be the same.